# How to wait inside SIGABRT signal handler

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

I have a signal handler for SIGABRT , when the signal is received, i need some more time for other threads to exit gracefully. Then I will do _exit() inside signal handler to exit the entire process.

But I am not sure how to wait inside a signal handler. I think there are some limitations for using sleep inside signal handler. I dont want to use busy wait.

Somebody suggest any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no limitations of what kind of code you can execute inside a signal handler. You just have to keep in mind that another signal may arrive while executing your signal handler leaving you in the middle of half finished functions, locked mutexes or other things that should better remain uninterrupted.

Normally you would have the signal handler set a flag signalling to all threads to nicely exit, return from the signal handler and then have your code gracefully exit.

Comment: the usleep() inside the SIGABRT make it hung for ever !

Comment: with usleep() inside a signal handler, which thread will go sleep ? Or the sigal handler will go sleeping ?

Comment: @LunarMushrooms The thread that is executing the signal handler will sleep. The reason it may be sleeping forever is because other signals may arrive in the meanwhile that interrupt that sleep and have the thread do something else. It is completely up to the implementation of the OS which thread will handle a signal, generally it's random.

Comment: I have two prints before and after usleep(), the one before usleep() is appearing. But the one after usleep() is not appearing(). It means usleep() is not interrupted , right ?

Comment: @LunarMushrooms It could mean anything. Use a debugger to find out what exactly is happening. A debugger will be able to tell you what a thread is doing exactly and then you may be able to find out why.

Comment: -1, Wrong: [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) explains very clearly that you should only call *async-signal-safe functions* inside signal handlers. For instance, a `printf` inside a signal handler is in principle not allowed (even if it usually works).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There is a difference between **should** and **can**. I explicitly wrote that you **can** call whatever you like. I also wrote that it is not recommended to call anything that can end up interrupted (is not signal safe).